# Number of distinct clusters in KMeans is less than n_clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, k-means, vgg-net

I have some food images stored in a single folder. All the images are unlabeled, nor are they stored into separate folder such as "pasta" or "meat". My current goal is to cluster the images into a number of categories so that I can later assess if the taste of foods depicted in images of the same cluster is similar.

To do that, I load the images and process them in a format that can be fed into the VGG16 for feature extraction and then pass the features to my KMeans to cluster the images. The code I am using is:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Hi\Documents\folder'
train_dir = os.path.join(path)
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
vgg16_feature_list = []
files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Hi\Documents\folder\*.jpg')
for i in enumerate(files):
    img = image.load_img(img_path,target_size=(224,224))
    img_data=image.img_to_array(img)
    img_data=np.expand_dims(img_data,axis=0)
    img_data=preprocess_input(img_data)

    vgg16_feature = model.predict(img_data)
    vgg16_feature_np = np.array(vgg16_feature)
    vgg16_feature_list.append(vgg16_feature_np.flatten())
vgg16_feature_list_np=np.array(vgg16_feature_list)
print(vgg16_feature_list_np.shape)
print(vgg16_feature_np.shape)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(vgg16_feature_list_np)
print(kmeans.labels_)
```

The issue is that I get the following warning:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (1) found smaller than n_clusters (3). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SKLearn KMeans Convergence Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727700/sklearn-kmeans-convergence-warning)

Comment: @xiawi I saw this in my search before answering, but the answer is from a purely coding side (how to suppress the warning itself), and not offering any actual remedies, so that's why I proceeded to offer a (different) answer myself.

Comment: What is “my KMeans”? Did you write that code? Is it in some standard library? Please see [mre] and [edit] your question accordingly. I’d expect Python code to start with some `import` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of these situations where, although your code is fine from a *programming* point of view, it does not produce satisfactory results due to an *ML*-related issue (data, model, or both), hence it is rather difficult to "debug" (I'm quoting the word, since this is not the typical debugging procedure, as the code itself runs fine).

At first instance, the situation seems to imply that there is not enough diversity in your features to justify 3 different clusters. And, provided that we remain in a K-means context, there is not much you can do; among the few options available (refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for details of the respective parameters):

- Increase the number of iterations `max_iter` (default 300)
- Increase the number of different centroid initializations `n_init` (default 10)
- Change the `init` argument to `random` (the default is `k-means++`) or, even better, provide a 3-element array with one sample from each of your targeted clusters (if you already have an idea which these clusters may actually be in your data)
- Run the model with different `random_state` values
- Combine the above

If nothing of the above works, it would very likely mean that K-means is actually not applicable here, and you may have to look for alternative approaches (which are out of the scope of this thread). Truth is, as correctly pointed out in the comment below, K-means does not usually work that well with data of such high dimensionality.

Comment: This is a great answer. To piggyback, KMeans doesn’t like such high dimensional data, you should use UMAP first and do dimensionality reduction

Comment: @SamH. thanks and you are correct indeed (updated answer to reflect this)